# How to prevent JBoss inter web application classpath?

Tags: java, jboss, classpath

I have two web application deployed in JBoss within same server. I have observed classpath is shared between this two web applications.

So how do I prevent classpath saring between applications. I mean whatever classes and jar files available in one application should not be visible in another application in same server in jboss.

Comment: Can you describe where the shared classes are deployed? Are they in the WEB-INF/lib directory of each war? Or are they in the JBOSS_HOME/server/standard/lib directory?

Comment: @McDowell I am using jboss-4.0.1sp1. @Kevin Stembridge Classes and Jars are deployed as part of web application. (WEB-INF/classes and WEB-INF/lib)

Answer (score 1):

For most versions of jBoss AS you need to update your jboss-web.xml file:

```
<jboss-web>
   <class-loading> 
      <loader-repository>com.example:archive=unique-archive-name</loader-repository> 
   </class-loading>
</jboss-web>
```

See the following reference for more info:

- [jBoss class loading configuration](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/classloadingconfiguration)
- [jBoss class loading background & use cases](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/jbossclassloadingusecases)

Answer (score 0):

The [JBoss wiki](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/classloadingconfiguration) states:

> In jboss-3.2.3, the
>   jbossweb-tomcat41.sar is configured to
>   use a unified class loader as the web
>   application class loader. This is
>   controlled by the `UseJBossWebLoader`
>   attribute in the
>   `jbossweb-tomcat41.sar/META-INF/jboss-service.xml`
>   descriptor. The use of a unified class
>   loader means that the classes
>   available in the war inside of the
>   `WEB-INF/classes` and `WEB-INF/lib`
>   are incorporated into the default
>   shared class loader repository. This
>   may not be what you want as its
>   contrary to the default servlet 2.3
>   class loading model and can result in
>   sharing of classes/resources between
>   web applications. You can disable this
>   by setting this attribute to false.

It goes on to say that this behaviour was changed in [4.0.2](http://jira.jboss.com/jira/browse/JBAS-1691), so it is a reasonable assumption that you still need to do this in 4.0.1.